# Tkinter button not defined because present inside a function

Tags: python, tkinter

**What I am trying to do:**

I want the button `Confirmar` to disappear once it is clicked, for that I redirected it to the function `dConfirm` which is supposed to trigger the destroy process.

**What is happening:**

The button is defined in a different function from the destroy process, so it is returning a *not defined error*.

**My code:**

```
def dSim():
    btn3=Button(janela, text= "Hipertensao arterial", command = add1) 
    btn3.place(x = 80, y = 219)
    btn4=Button(janela, text= "Pedras nos rins", command = add2) 
    btn4.place(x = 200, y = 219)
    btn5=Button(janela, text= "Osteoporose", command = add3) 
    btn5.place(x = 295, y = 219)
    btn6=Button(janela, text= "Colesterol elevado", command = add4) 
    btn6.place(x = 378, y = 219)
    btn7=Button(janela, text= "Esclerose multipla", command = add5) 
    btn7.place(x = 492, y = 219)
    btn.destroy()
    btn2.destroy()
    lb7=Label(janela, text= "Selecione as suas doencas:", font = ("Verdana", "14"))
    lb7.place(x = 185, y = 190)
    btn8=Button(janela, text= "Confirmar", command = dConfirm) 
    btn8.place(x = 80, y = 240)

def dNao():
    lb5=Label(janela, text=Gperf, font = ("Verdana", "14"))
    lb5.place(x = 80, y = 165)
    btn.destroy()
    btn2.destroy()
    lb6=Label(janela, text="E perfeitamente saudavel, otimo!", font = ("Verdana", "14"))
    lb6.place(x = 185, y = 190)

def dConfirm():
    btn8.destroy()
```

Comment: `btn8` is a local variable of `dSim()`.  It simply *does not exist anymore* when you attempt to use it in `dConfirm()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have three options:

1. `btn8` is a **local** variable, so you cannot refer to it outside its scope. You can make it **global**.
2. Instead of directly calling `dConfirm()`, pass to it the button instance using a `lambda` like this:
   `btn8 = Button(janela, text="Confirmar", command=lambda: dConfirm(btn8))` and change the function definition to `def dConfirm(btn8):`(I would prefer this if you don't want to move to option 3 and modify your code)
3. If you are using classes, make it an instance of the class by using `self.btn8` and then destroy it by using `self.btn8.destroy()`.

Answer (score 1):

**#1** You can try this:

```
import tkinter as tk
root = tk.Tk()
frame = tk.Frame(root)
frame.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=4, pady=4)

# destroy the button on dConfirm function call
def dConfirm():
    btn8.destroy()

# Declare btn8 outside of the two function
btn8 = tk.Button(frame, text="Confirmar", command=dConfirm)

# Place btn8 inside the function you want
def dSim():
    btn8.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=4, pady=4)
dSim()
root.mainloop()
```

**#2** You can also try this (In my opinion this is better):

```
import tkinter as tk

class MainWindow:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master

        self.frame = tk.Frame(self.master)
        self.frame.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=4, pady=4)
        self.dSim()

    def dConfirm(self):
        self.btn8.destroy()

    def dSim(self):
        self.btn8 = tk.Button(self.frame, text="Confirmar", command=self.dConfirm)
        self.btn8.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=4, pady=4)

def main():
    root = tk.Tk()
    app = MainWindow(root)
    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```